# C# Search JSON file and select node

Tags: c#, json, search

So I have an application that uses the Newtonsoft.Json dll and I need to search a JSON file for a value entered by the user, then select the node with that value in.

[JSON Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OI7jV.png)

So the user will search for the 'name' tag and I need to be able to fetch the 'ID' of the node.

Example:

1. Name: Blimp
2. -----------------Fetching ID-----------------
3. ID: 302686

Comment: Anything you have tried? What is the actual question.. Also post json as text (code formatted) and not picture

Comment: This is a fairly broad question, when you say you have a file and you are using NewtonSoft.Json, have you already parsed the entire file into a collection?  Do you still need to do that?  How big is the file that you are searching?  Are the names unique or do you need to return more than 1? Please clarify exactly what part of the problem you are stuck on and provide the related code.

Comment: please post the json as string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as the item you want to (actually) search is an array, you'd have to deserialize the JSON into a C# object. Then, you can access the array, on which you can unleash search functions like a LINQ expression:

```
var item = Array
    .Where(x => x.name == given_name)
    .Select(x => x.id);
```

or Lambda:

```
var index = Array.FindIndex(x => x.name.Equals(given_name));
var item = Array[index];
```